# Is conversion of image to byte array in android heavy task?

Tags: android

I am converting image as a byte array to store in the database in android. For this, I have to convert image both at the time of storing and reading. I can definitely store all image in variables during runtime at once but it might take a lot of space if there are a lot of images in the database. Does conversion actually take a lot of resources ? in that case I will use other methods to store like in file (I haven't used file before so will have to learn it first, trying to save effort :) ).

Comment: I wonder where and how you have images. Mostly there are jpg files on phone storage. But images. Where? Putting a file in a byte array is pretty simple. And it is not called a conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it depends on how many images are you planning to save in the database. For instance: if it is the user profile image, which is gonna be one image per user, I think it is okay. But, if it is something like images that the user can upload as many images as he likes, I don't really think it is a good idea. There are advantages and disadvantages on both.

There are plenty discussions about those two approaches:

[Storing images in a database versus a filesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25196910/storing-images-in-a-database-versus-a-filesystem)

[Why is it considered bad to store images in a database?](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-it-considered-bad-to-store-images-in-a-database)

[Storing Images in DB - Yea or Nay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay)

[What is the best place for storing uploaded images, SQL database or disk file system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348363/what-is-the-best-place-for-storing-uploaded-images-sql-database-or-disk-file-sy)

Comment: Thanks for the help. After looking at links I guess it's better to store in a file. It will work faster and I don't want a laggy app.